# How to use sed to search and replace a pattern who appears multiple times in the same line?

Tags: regex, sed

Because the question can be misleading, here is a little example. I have this kind of file:

```
some text
some text @@some-text-KEY-some-other-text@@
text again @@some-text-KEY-some-other-text@@ @@some-text-KEY-some-other-text@@
again @@some-text-KEY-some-other-text-KEY-text@@
some text with KEY @@KEY-some-text@@
blabla @@KEY@@
```

In this example, I want to replace each occurrence of `KEY-` inside a pair of `@@` by `VALUE-`. I started with this sed command:

```
sed -i 's/\(@@[^@]*\)KEY-\([^@]*@@\)/\1VALUE-\2/g'
```

Here is how it works:

1. `\(@@[^@]*\)`: create a first group composed of two `@` and any characters except `@` ...
2. `KEY-`: ... until the last occurrence of `KEY-` on that line
3. `\([^@]*@@\)`: and create a second group with all the characters except `@` until the next pair of `@`.

The problem is my command can't handle correctly the following line because there are multiple `KEY-` inside my pair of `@@`:

```
again @@some-text-KEY-some-other-text-KEY-text@@
```

Indeed, I get this result:

```
again @@some-text-KEY-some-other-text-VALUE-text@@
```

If I want to replace all the occurrences of `KEY-` in that line, I have to run my command multiple times and I prefer to avoid that. I also tried with lazy operators but the problem is the same.

How can I create a regex and a sed command who can handle correctly all my file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is rather complex: you need to replace all occurrences of some multicharacter text inside blocks of text between *identical* multicharacter delimiters.

The easiest and safest way to solve the task is using Perl:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(@@)(.*?)(@@)/$end_delim=$3; "$1" . $2=~s|KEY-|VALUE-|gr . "$end_delim"/ge' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/PxEZ4z).

The `(@@)(.*?)(@@)` pattern will match strings between two adjacent `@@` substrings capturing the start delimiter into Group 1, end delimiter in Group 3, and all text in between into Group 2. Since the regex substitution re-sets all placeholders, the temporary variable is used to keep the value of the end delimiter (`$end_delim=$3`), then, `"$1" . $2=~s|KEY-|VALUE-|gr . "$end_delim"` replaces the match with the value in the Group 1 of the first match (the first `@@`), then the Group 2 value with all `KEY-` replaced with `VALUE-`, and then the end delimiter.

**If there are no `KEY-`s in between matches on the same line** you may use a branch with `sed` by enclosing your command with `:A` and `tA`:

```
sed -i ':A; s/\(@@[^@]*\)KEY-\([^@]*@@\)/\1VALUE-\2/g; tA' file
```

Note you missed the first placeholder in `\VALUE-\2`, it should be `\1VALUE-\2`.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/QJfA3V):

```
s="some KEY- text
some text @@some-text-KEY-some-other-text@@
text again @@some-text-KEY-some-other-text@@ @@some-text-KEY-some-other-text@@
again @@some-text-KEY-some-other-text-KEY-text@@
some text with KEY @@KEY-some-text@@
blabla @@KEY@@"

sed ':A; s/\(@@[^@]*\)KEY-\([^@]*@@\)/\1VALUE-\2/g; tA' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
some KEY- text
some text @@some-text-VALUE-some-other-text@@
text again @@some-text-VALUE-some-other-text@@ @@some-text-VALUE-some-other-text@@
again @@some-text-VALUE-some-other-text-VALUE-text@@
some text with KEY @@VALUE-some-text@@
blabla @@KEY@@
```

**More details**:

`sed` allows the usage of loops and [branches](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sed/sed_branches.htm). The `:A` in the code above is a *label*, a special location marker that can be "jumped at" using the appropriate operator. `t` is  used to create a branch, this "*command jumps to the label only if the previous substitute command was successful*". So, once the pattern matched and the replacement occurred, `sed` goes back to where it was and re-tries a match. If it is not successful, `sed` goes on to search for the matches further in the string. So, `tA` means *go back to the location marked with `A` if there was a successful search-and-replace operation*.

Comment: Can you explain what `:A` and `tA` do? I never saw them.

Comment: @Pierre I added the details below the demo.

Comment: What if there was a `KEY-` or more between the end of one delimiter and the start of another?

Comment: @potong Could you please ask OP? I do not know what scenarios they want to support.

Comment: @potong In my use case, I shouldn't replace it. But, you're right, this sed command will.

Comment: @Pierre I [understand now](https://ideone.com/UV3Fvs), the problem is due to the fact the starting and ending delimiters are the same. I am not sure there is an efficient way to solve it with `sed` though. I added the Perl solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/@@/\n/g;:a;s/^([^\n]*(\n[^\n]*\n[^\n]*)*\n[^\n]*)KEY-/\1VALUE-/;ta;s/\n/@@/g' file
```

Convert `@@`'s to newlines. Using a loop, replace `VAL-` between matched newlines to `VALUE-`. When all done replace newlines by `@@`'s.